# Would a dual French-Lebanon citizen be expelled from Lebanon if they had entered Lebanon illegally?

Tags: france, dual-citizenship, lebanon

I read on https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2020-01-14/how-nissan-s-carlos-ghosn-was-smuggled-out-of-japan:

> He had two French passports, a privilege granted to citizens with particularly demanding travel schedules. He’d received permission to keep the second one; Japanese law requires foreigners to carry their identity documents at all times. The caveat was that it had to be kept in a plastic case, sealed with a lock to which only his lawyers had the combination. But Ghosn got it open and later presented it to an inspector at Beirut’s Rafic Hariri International Airport like any other traveler. It was the first legal act he’d performed since leaving Japan.

Would Ghosn have been expelled from Lebanon if he had entered Lebanon illegally? To rephrase the question more generally, would a dual French-Lebanon citizen be expelled from Lebanon if they had entered Lebanon illegally?

Comment: I don't know Lebanese law, but the immigration laws I do know cannot be applied to the country's own citizens.  Under these laws a citizen cannot be expelled, regardless of what other citizenship they may possess and regardless of how they entered the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he is indeed a Lebanese citizen he cannot be deported from Lebanon. The essence of citizenship is that it is a place from which you cannot be deported. He might be punished for violating Lebanese law regarding identity documents, but the remedy of deportation or expulsion would not be available.